# Updating value of one column in dataframe if ID match found in column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes. The second dataframe is a derived from the first dataframe. I update a column in the second dataframe, and then I want to put the updated values back in the first dataframe. I have tried "merge", but it gives me two columns with suffixes "_x" and "_y"

```
import pandas

lotQtyQueryForDF = pandas.read_sql_query(refreshQuery,conForInfo)
dataFrameOfLots = pandas.DataFrame(lotQtyQueryForDF,columns=['Customer','Stage','ProdType','Brand','ProdName','Size','Strength','Lot','PackedOn','Qty','Available'])

dataFrameOfLots['Available']=dataFrameOfLots["Available"].fillna(dataFrameOfLots['Qty'])
#inserting columns
dataFrameOfLots['QtyInTransaction']=0   
dataFrameOfLots['IndexCol'] = range(1, len(dataFrameOfLots) + 1)

dataFrameFiltered=dataFrameOfLots.query('Brand=="XYZ" & Customer=="ABC"')
dataFrameFiltered.loc[:,'Qty in transaction']=34
dataFrameFiltered2=dataFrameFiltered[['Qty in transaction','IndexCol']].copy()
dataFrameOfLots.merge(dataFrameFiltered2,on='IndexCol',how='outer')
```

Input Dataset:

```
Customer Stage ProdType Brand ProdName Size Strength Lot PackedOn Qty Available

DEF      A       Bulk    YYY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            

ABC      A       Bulk    XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            

GHI      A       Bulk    YTY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            

ABC      B       RAW     XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5
```

Actual output:

```
Customer Stage ProdType Brand ProdName Size Strength Lot PackedOn Qty Available QtyInTransaction_x IndexCol QtyInTransaction_y

DEF      A       Bulk    YYY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            0               1             0 

ABC      A       Bulk    XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            0               2             34 

GHI      A       Bulk    YTY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            0               3             0 

ABC      B       RAW     XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5            0               4             34
```

Expected output:

```
Customer Stage ProdType Brand ProdName Size Strength Lot PackedOn Qty Available IndexCol QtyInTransaction

DEF      A       Bulk    YYY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5           1             0 

ABC      A       Bulk    XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5           2             34 

GHI      A       Bulk    YTY   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5           3             0 

ABC      B       RAW     XYZ   Test    Test   Weak    1   20200101 10    5           4             34
```

Is query the right approach?
How would I merge so that only one column shows up?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give input datasets. All there is is an sql query and we cant read your database

Comment: Added the input dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try use outer merge and drop unrequired rows after you do your filters. Code below.

```
result=pd.merge(dataFrameOfLots, dataFrameFiltered, how='outer', on=['Customer', 'Stage', 'ProdType', 'Brand', 'ProdName', 'Size',
       'Strength', 'Lot', 'PackedOn', 'Qty', 'Available'],suffixes=('_x', '')).fillna(0)
result=result.loc[:,~result.columns.str.endswith('_x')]#drop unwanted columns
```

or

```
result.drop(columns=['QtyInTransaction_x','IndexCol_x'], inplace=True)#drop unwanted columns
```

Comment: Thanks, although the line:
`result.loc[:,~result.columns.str.endswith('_x')]` 
does not seem to have an impact.

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing. Thank you.